# Display date and time in input

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the code below. I added a script in the HTML to display time and date in the Interview Start time input (Interview End Time not added yet.
For some reason this does not work and only shows the time for a split second before automatically deleting it.

I tried changing the location of the script, but that didn't work. How would I make the start time stay there, and also output on submit?

```js
const idToBold = [ 'start', 'name', 'profile', 'application', 'age', 'dob', 'origin', 'language' ];
var formInfo = {};

function showInput() {
  $('input').each(function(){
      var input = $(this);
      
      //here you check every <input type="text">
      if(input.attr('type') == 'text'){
        var value = input.val();
        
        //check if the id is in the constant of ids that need to add the [B] tag
        if(idToBold.includes(input.attr('id'))){
          value = '[b]' + value + '[/b]';
        }
        var label = $("label[for='"+input.attr('id')+"']").text();
        formInfo[label] = value;
      }
   
   //Age Check
      if(input.attr('name') == 'ageCondition' && input.is(':checked')){
        var message = null;
      
        //check the value, theres: 'pass' and 'fail'.
        if(input.val() == 'Yes'){
          message = '[b][Color = Blue]Match[/color][/b]';
        }else{
          message = '[b][Color = yellow]Age and Date of Birth do not match[/color][/b]';
        };
        var label = $("label[for='"+input.attr('name')+"']").text();
        formInfo[label] = message;
      }
      
      //Passed Interview
      if(input.attr('name') == 'passCondition' && input.is(':checked')){
        var message = null;
      
        //check the value, theres: 'pass' and 'fail'.
        if(input.val() == 'pass'){
          message = '[b][Color = Green]User has passed the interview [/color][/b]';
        }else{
          message = '[Color = Red]User hase failed the interview.[/color][/b]';
        };
        var label = $("label[for='"+input.attr('name')+"']").text();
        formInfo[label] = message;
      }
      
  });
  
  //you can remove this, just for output purpose
  var formInfoFormated = '';
  jQuery.each(formInfo, function(key, value){
    formInfoFormated += key + ': ' + value + '<br>';
  });
  $('#display').html(formInfoFormated);
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: #384047;
}

form {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
}


h1 {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="url"],
textarea,
select {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
}

select {
  padding: 6px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.input_submit {
  padding: 19px 39px 18px 39px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #4bc970;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #3ac162;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

label.light {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline;
}

.number {
  background-color: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

  form {
    max-width: 480px;
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src ="javascript/supportJS.js"></script>
 <title>Arma Life - Interview Logger</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 
  <script>
    var time = new Date();
    function show(id) {
   if (id == 1) {
   document.getElementById('start').value=time;
   }

   if(id == 2) {
   document.getElementById('end').value=time;
   }
    }
 </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form>
  <label for="start"><b>Interview Start Time</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="start">
  <button id='1' onClick="show(this.id)">Click Amber</button>
  <label for="name"><b>Roleplay Name</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="name">
  <label for="profile"><b>Profile Link</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="profile">
  <label for="application"><b>Application Link</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="application">
  
  <br><br>
  <label for="age"><b>Age</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="age">
  <label for="dob"><b>Date of Birth</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="dob">
  <label for="ageCondition"><b>Date of Birth and Age match?</b></label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="ageCondition" value="Yes">Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ageCondition" value="No">No<br>
  <br><br>
  
  <label for="origin"><b>Country of Origin</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="origin">
  <label for="language"><b>Primary Language</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="language">
  
  <br><br>
  <label for="passCondition"><b>Passed?</b></label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="passCondition" value="pass">Pass<br>
  <input type="radio" name="passCondition" value="fail">Fail<br>
  <br><br>
   </form>
   
   <input class="input_submit" type="submit" onclick="showInput();">

   <label>Your input: </label>
   <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML `button` elements are by default of type `submit`.

If you click on this button, you immediately submit the form:

```
<button id='1' onClick="show(this.id)">Click Amber</button>
```

To make this button only performs the action defined on `click`, without submitting the form, just give it a type of `button`.

```
<button id='1' type="button" onClick="show(this.id)">Click Amber</button>
```

```js
const idToBold = [ 'start', 'name', 'profile', 'application', 'age', 'dob', 'origin', 'language' ];
var formInfo = {};


function showInput() {
  $('input').each(function(){
      var input = $(this);
      
      //here you check every <input type="text">
      if(input.attr('type') == 'text'){
        var value = input.val();
        
        //check if the id is in the constant of ids that need to add the [B] tag
        if(idToBold.includes(input.attr('id'))){
          value = '[b]' + value + '[/b]';
        }
        var label = $("label[for='"+input.attr('id')+"']").text();
        formInfo[label] = value;
      }
   
   //Age Check
      if(input.attr('name') == 'ageCondition' && input.is(':checked')){
        var message = null;
      
        //check the value, theres: 'pass' and 'fail'.
        if(input.val() == 'Yes'){
          message = '[b][Color = Blue]Match[/color][/b]';
        }else{
          message = '[b][Color = yellow]Age and Date of Birth do not match[/color][/b]';
        };
        var label = $("label[for='"+input.attr('name')+"']").text();
        formInfo[label] = message;
      }
      
      //Passed Interview
      if(input.attr('name') == 'passCondition' && input.is(':checked')){
        var message = null;
      
        //check the value, theres: 'pass' and 'fail'.
        if(input.val() == 'pass'){
          message = '[b][Color = Green]User has passed the interview [/color][/b]';
        }else{
          message = '[Color = Red]User hase failed the interview.[/color][/b]';
        };
        var label = $("label[for='"+input.attr('name')+"']").text();
        formInfo[label] = message;
      }
      
  });
  
  //you can remove this, just for output purpose
  var formInfoFormated = '';
  jQuery.each(formInfo, function(key, value){
    formInfoFormated += key + ': ' + value + '<br>';
  });
  $('#display').html(formInfoFormated);
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: #384047;
}

form {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
}


h1 {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="url"],
textarea,
select {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
}

select {
  padding: 6px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.input_submit {
  padding: 19px 39px 18px 39px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #4bc970;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #3ac162;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

label.light {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline;
}

.number {
  background-color: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

  form {
    max-width: 480px;
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src ="javascript/supportJS.js"></script>
 <title>Arma Life - Interview Logger</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 
  <script>
    var time = new Date();
    function show(id) {
   if (id == 1) {
   document.getElementById('start').value=time;
   }

   if(id == 2) {
   document.getElementById('end').value=time;
   }
    }
 </script>


</head>
<body>

   <form>
  <label for="start"><b>Interview Start Time</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="start">
  <button id='1' type="button" onClick="show(this.id)">Click Amber</button>
  <label for="name"><b>Roleplay Name</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="name">
  <label for="profile"><b>Profile Link</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="profile">
  <label for="application"><b>Application Link</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="application">
  
  <br><br>
  <label for="age"><b>Age</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="age">
  <label for="dob"><b>Date of Birth</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="dob">
  <label for="ageCondition"><b>Date of Birth and Age match?</b></label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="ageCondition" value="Yes">Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" name="ageCondition" value="No">No<br>
  <br><br>
  
  <label for="origin"><b>Country of Origin</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="origin">
  <label for="language"><b>Primary Language</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="language">
  
  <br><br>
  <label for="passCondition"><b>Passed?</b></label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="passCondition" value="pass">Pass<br>
  <input type="radio" name="passCondition" value="fail">Fail<br>
  <br><br>
   </form>
   
   <input class="input_submit" type="submit" onclick="showInput();">

   <label>Your input: </label>
   <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to keep your content from disappearing remove the form tags. From what I see your have to form element present but you're not using it for their intended purpose. The form tag is trying to do a POST (which is why everything looks like it disappearing) when you click your "Click Amber" button. The form thinks that your button is there to do a "Submit".

Here is more information about html form elements:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can add `type="button"` to the "Click Amber" button to prevent your form from submitting on that press. As been said, your form is submitting which is clearing out your page.

Your output code already works correctly.

```
<button id='1' type="button" onClick="show(this.id)">Click Amber</button>
```